# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'events[genre][0]')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a custom array but the for loop cannot evaluate events[genre][0].name as events has not been set yet due to the async nature of firebase. Is there any way to only execute the for loop once the data has been set or any workaround for this?

```
const Finalized = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
  const testEvents = ["arts", "leisure", "sports"];  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("events")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setEvents(snapshot.val());
      });
  });

  let dataJson = {};
  for (i = 0; i < testEvents.length; i++) {
    let genre = testEvents[i];
    dataJson.time = "09:00";
    dataJson.title = "Event" + i;
    dataJson.description = <Text>{events[genre][0].name} </Text>;  //cannot be evaluated as undefined
  }
  console.log(dataJson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must not execute the useEffect without any dependency specially since its sets a state within it, otherwise your App will go into an infinite loop

Secondly, you can have a loading state before actually using the resolved data

```
const Finalized = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const testEvents = ["arts", "leisure", "sports"];  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("events")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setEvents(snapshot.val());
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []); // executed on initial render

  if(isLoading) {
     return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  let dataJson = {};
  for (i = 0; i < testEvents.length; i++) {
    let genre = testEvents[i];
    dataJson.time = "09:00";
    dataJson.title = "Event" + i;
    dataJson.description = <Text>{events[genre][0].name} </Text>;  //cannot be evaluated as undefined
  }
  console.log(dataJson);
```

Comment: @ Shubham Thanks a lot for the answer, especially for the first point. I was initially confused why adding a console.log into the .then block caused my terminal to be flooded with output

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for `events` to be fulfilled, you can achieve this that way :

```js
const Finalized = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
  const testEvents = ["arts", "leisure", "sports"];  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("events")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setEvents(snapshot.val());
      });

    if (events.length) {
      // use you loop here
    }
  }, events.length);

  ...
}
```